# IdFtp.List throws socket-error #10054 occasionally

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy10

When I call the function

```
IdFtp.List(myList, '', false);
```

afterwards I have logged in and changed the ftp directory, I get a socket-error #10054 exception ("Connection reset by peer.") occesionally.

When I call that function e.g. 20 times consecutively I get that exception 1 time.

That problem I have only encountered on Vista OS.

Does anybody know what the problem is or how I can avoid it?

Comment: I got a similar issue when connecting, due to the `FEAT` command not being supported on my server, I set `idftp.AutoIssueFEAT` to false and  the problem went away. But you're getting the same issue from a different source, not sure what it is in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Not much you can do about this, because the disconnection is done by the FTP server. 
You have a few choices:

- Increase (or disable) the timeout settings (every FTP server has a different name for it) on your FTP Server connection settings.
- Tell server that you are alive by sending `NOOP` command periodically (switching to Passive mode can also help).
- Catch that exception and reconnect silently (This is my preferred solution because we have many FTP servers and I don't trust the sys-admins to change the FTP server time-out settings).

---

Here is a screen-shot from `FileZilla` FTP server time-out settings:

[image]

Note that with the above settings, the FTP client will be disconnected after 2 min of non-activity.
setting that value to 0, will disable the time-out.

Comment: On my machine and on the most other clients it is working without any problem (And therefore I cannot reproduce). I think it depends on the client machine.

Answer (score 2):

The FTP protocol uses multiple socket connections.  Every time you call `List()`, a new socket connection is established to transfer the requested listing data.  It sounds like the FTP server is not always closing the socket correctly at the end of a transfer.

Comment: The strange thing is, that almost the first call throws an exception. I just checked the ftp server log file, how other tools LIST files (iexplorer, firefox). One difference is that they use PASSIVE mode, and then a different PORT for data transfer is used.

Comment: The `PORT` command is used for Active mode transfers, where the FTP server connects to the client. The `PASV` command is used for passive transfers, where the client connects to the FTP server. Passive mode transfers are more firewall/router friendly for clients to use. `TIdFTP` has a `Passive` property for specifying which mode to use. Either way, the FTP server disconnects the socket when the requested data is finished being transferred, which could cause the 10054 error if done incorrectly. I will look into updating Indy to handle that better, but I have no ETA on that right now.

Answer (score 0):

In the component "IdFTP", change the following properties:

- "Passive" = "False"
- "TransferType" = "ftASCII"